# How to get friends Email id from facebook using asp.net code

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get friends Email id from facebook using asp.net  code

Answer (score 1):

You can use facebook API:

API:    http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:C_Sharp
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:ASP.NET
SDK:    http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com
Code:   http://facebook.codeplex.com
Others:     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee388574.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its possible to simply harvest the email accounts from a facebook account because I dont know what anti-spam measures they have in place.

Microsoft and Facebook have actually partnered up via a 3rd party company to provide an asp.net facebook developers kit:

- http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=microsoft+sdk+for+facebook+platform